# shell script returning not found on jenkins master using pipeline as code

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am new to jenkins and trying to write a pipeline. Everything is working when run with jobs, but facing issue with pipeline. My script which should run after checking out from github returns file not found. Could anyone help please. Attached is the image of the log.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuxGn.png
Below is the code sample I am trying to execute.

```
 stage('puppet master config checkout') {
        steps {
            echo "cloning github"
            git "https://github.com/rk280392/pipeline_scripts.git"
        }

    }
     stage('puppet master config build') { 
        steps {
            echo "running puppet master script"
            sh "puppet_master.sh"
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the folder structure of your git-repo? You are calling the script but missing the correct folder structure in Jenkins.

Comment: can see the folder and script under the folders:- 
                                         root@vagrant:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace# ls          
pipeline_script  pipeline_script@2  pipeline_script@2@tmp  pipeline_script@tmp

Comment: solved. Needed to use ./puppet_master.sh

Answer (score 0):

1. check the file script is here with command sh 'ls' just after the git step.
   generally I would recommend not to use git step but checkout instead, it is more powerful and more reliable

```
    checkout([
         $class: 'GitSCM',
         branches: scm.branches,
         extensions: scm.extensions,
         userRemoteConfigs: [[
             url: 'https://github.com/rk280392/pipeline_scripts.git'
         ]]
    ])
```

2. is your script executable? you could use `chmod +x puppet_master.sh` before running it with dot slash as prefix `./puppet_master.sh`

```
sh 'sh puppet_master.sh'
```